# Categorize Key-Value Pairs/Alternative to HashMap of HashMap

Tags: data-structures, rust, hashmap, queue, categories

I'm creating a generic matchmaking server and basically, there is an Enum that defines the possible game modes a player can queue (not really one since game modes can sort the queue, like ranked modes) into. So, when a player decides to join a queue, their connection ID is added to a HashMap (currently still a Vec, but realized that a HashMap is better) of IDs and their respective data. That HashMap is also stored in a HashMap with the key being the game mode.

But when I looked into removing the user when they leave, I realized that I would have to iterate over the game modes and try to remove the user from each (at least until I find them).

This isn't too much of a problem, it happens under the hood, this is more my curiosity at work. I just wonder if there is a data structure that uses unique key-value pairs but provides views of data (categories). So something that would look like ViewHashMap<K, V, C>. Or is there something better for this purpose/I should organize my data different?

Code example of what I'm doing:

```
if let Some(queue) = queues.get_mut(game_mode) {
      queue.insert(id, data);
}

// and
for queue in queues.iter_mut() {
      if queue.remove(id).is_some() {
             break;
      }
}
```

Comment: This is reminiscent of a multi-index map (i.e. a map that has multiple lookup methods) but its just enough different that you'd likely need a bespoke implementation. A better alternative though I think would be to track the player's state with the connection, so if they disconnect you'll already know which queue they were in.

Comment: @kmdreko It would be nice if it was simple enough that I could store the game state with users, but I need some way of iterating over users in each game mode. I could just generate views of a list of all players every time I need to match players, but that seems like it would be slower than using a hashmap. Maybe I'll try creating my own implementation for a "CategorizedHashMap" some time.